# Trying to run LibreOffice (soffice) as a systemctl service fails

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, libreoffice, systemctl, soffice

I'm trying to get LibreOffice (more specifically, soffice) to run as a service on an Ubuntu server (20.04.3), but I've just not been able to make it work. It's the first time I'm trying to set up a custom service, so the likelihood that it's just configured wrong is very high.

Basically, I want to keep soffice running in headless mode, listening in a socket. The command I use for it is:

```
/usr/bin/soffice --headless --accept='socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;' --nofirststartwizard
```

From all I can see, this command seems to be working. No output whatsoever when I run it manually, and it blocks the terminal, supposedly waiting for incoming connections.

So, to run it as a service, I created the following `soffice.service` file on `/etc/systemd/system`:

```
[Unit]
Description=LibreOffice service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=soffice "--headless --accept='socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;' --nofirststartwizard"
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=simple
StandardError=syslog
User=www-data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After enabling and starting it, I get the following on `systemctl status soffice`:

```
● soffice.service - LibreOffice service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/soffice.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-02-06 17:18:40 WET; 4s ago
    Process: 24786 ExecStart=/usr/bin/soffice --headless --accept='socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;' --nofirststartwizard (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 24786 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I'm guessing the issue is on the `ExecStart` directive, but despite reading the documentation – which is hard to follow for me, since I only use linux to keep my webserver running – I just couldn't figure out what was wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it was the double quotes on the ExecStart that were causing trouble. I'll test everything and edit this answer once I'm sure it's working.